# Extension of Brahmagupta's formula to cyclic polygons in terms of side lengths

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How is area $A$  of a cyclic scalene pentagon $(n=5) $ derived?

With

$$ s = \frac{a+b+c+d+e}{5}, $$

as

$$ A ^{(n+1)/2} = A^3 = s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)(s-e)?$$

If not, how else?

And also how exactly is $A$ generalized for $n$ sided polygons? Thanks for neat generalization attempts for cyclic expressions of cyclic polygons... with a check when $n$ goes to infinity and polygon gets regular $ A = \pi R^2 $ is recovered.

Comment: See link below for a "formula" for cyclic pentagon, it still involves a lot of symmetric terms but it's very long and expressed as a root of a degree 7 polynomial. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CyclicPentagon.html

Answer (score 0):

Your formula does not hold for a regular pentagon. For this, your formula would give $$A^3=2.5z\cdot (1.5z)^5 = 18.984375z^6$$

so $A=\sqrt[3]{18.984375}z^2 \approx 2.67z^2$, but the correct formula is $A=\frac{{ \sqrt {25 + 10\sqrt 5 } }}{4} z^2 \approx 1.72z^2$.

I've never seen an extension of Brahmagupta's formula to cyclic n-gons.

---

A closer approximation would be $$A \approx \sqrt{\frac{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)(s-e)}{s}}$$

This is approximately $1.74z^2$ for a regular pentagon.

Notice that this also fits better in the "sequence" $\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$, $\sqrt{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)}$, ... , i.e. one removes an $s$ and adds a $s-\mathrm{side}$.

Comment: I'm sorry for all the mistakes in the initial post, but I've fixed them now.

Comment: Thanks,ok. What I gave was only for a start, Looking for a generalization. I can't believe it  does n't exist.